# What kind of SSL implementation do I go for?

Tags: java, ssl, html-components, jsse

I am currently testing the waters of SSL, and am new to the SSL stuff. As a part of my research, I came across two different implementations of SSL in the java space.

First, let me state my requirement, which is very simple, I just need a process to post data to a URL using https.

Among the two solutions, the first one is a pure Java implementation (using only the core Java classes) and the other one uses the Apache HTTPClient to do it's http.

Initially, as a part of my testing, I would get the infamous "unable to find valid certification path to requested target " exception, and this I figured happens when the certificate (received from the server) is not part of the Java key store. Once I add the certificate to the Java Key store, the application works fine in both cases. 
However, in my use of HTTPClient, I noticed the use of SSLSocketFactory.

When I tested HttpClient with the following code,

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        PostMethod postMethod = new PostMethod(target);
        postMethod.setQueryString("someQueryString");

        try {
            httpClient.executeMethod(postMethod);
            System.out.println("Response code: " +  postMethod.getStatusLine());



            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(postMethod.getResponseBodyAsStream()));
            String temp;
            while ((temp = in.readLine()) != null){
              response += temp + "\n";
             }
            temp = null;
            in.close ();
            System.out.println("Server response:\n'" + response + "'");

        } catch (HttpException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            postMethod.releaseConnection();
        }
```

it worked fine, so I am not sure what is the use of SSLSocketFactory implementations? I initially thought this is useful, when we want to automate the addition of the certificate to the key store. Am I right in that analysis?

If my analysis is true, which implementation is better?

- Is it better to just manually install the certificate? What are the cons of this approach? and will the certificate expire? If it does, would I have to install a new certificate again?
- Or should I automate the whole key store addition functionality using SSLSocketFactory?

Your inputs would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You should do neither.  There are existing solutions to this.

[From the docs](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/sslguide.html#Examples_of_SSL_customization_in_HttpClient):

> There are several custom socket factories available in our
>   contribution package. They can be a good start for those who seek to
>   tailor the behavior of the HTTPS protocol to the specific needs of
>   their application:
>
> - EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory can be used to create SSL
>     connections that allow the target server to authenticate with a
>     self-signed certificate.
> - StrictSSLProtocolSocketFactory can be used to create SSL
>     connections that can optionally perform host name verification in
>     order to help preventing man-in-the-middle type of attacks.
> - AuthSSLProtocolSocketFactory can be used to optionally enforce
>     mutual client/server authentication. This is the most flexible
>     implementation of a protocol socket factory. It allows for
>     customization of most, if not all, aspects of the SSL authentication.

Comment: hmm, as far as I know, I don't need any SSL customization. When I tried to use HTTPClient out of the box, the only error I got was "unable to find valid certification path to requested target" which I resolved by making the server certificate a part of the Java Key store. So would this implementation be the best option for me?

Answer (score 1):

> I came across two different implementations of SSL in the java space.

No you didn't. You came across the built-in JSSE and some stuff that Apache has built *around* it. The message 'unable to find valid certification path to requested target' for example comes from JSSE, indeed from JCE.

The only other implementation of JSSE itself that I am aware of is in the IBM JVM.